# Given function never gets executed despite being called properly and compiler throwing no error

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

The following snippet from a long long bunch of C++ sources and header files (which I will be happy to share in case they are needed) shows the user-defined function(or object?) `Read` being called as part of a Multi-threading operation that is going on.

As part of identifying the problem, I printed flags just before and after the function is called:

> `std::cout<<"Before calling\n";`

and

> `std::cout<<"After calling\n";`

I have also inserted a flag to be printed just after the function is called:

> `std::cout<<"Entered the function";`

The entire application compiles perfectly and also runs smoothly - until this function **`Read`** is called, it never gets executed.

In the output, you get the "Before calling" and "After calling" but never the "Entered function".

Operating system used is Ubuntu 16.04, with the g++ compiler.

As of now I am only sharing two snippets related to the question - (since a single file is around 1500 lines of code; I think it should suffice, let me know if otherwise)

Following is the snippet of the thread in which function is called **(at line 130)** and then is the other file where the function is defined.

Thread where the Function is  called:

```
1 void* StartGenericReadThread(void *ThreadAr)
2   {       //std::cout<<"flag GenericThread\n";
3    //printf("\nSuccess");
4           int PORT = ((ThreadArg*)ThreadAr)->PORT;
5    #ifdef WIN32
6           Sleep(4000);
7    #else
8           sleep(4);
9    #endif     
10          DSDMux *Mux;
11          DSDConfigReader *cfg;
12          SNMPTrap    Trap;
13          DSDMessageSender *DMS;
14          Mux = ((ThreadArg*)ThreadAr)->Mux;
15          cfg = ((ThreadArg*)ThreadAr)->cfg;
16          DMS = ((ThreadArg*)ThreadAr)->MSG;
17          
18          
19      strcpy(DMS->SNMP_DET.DSD_MAN_IP,cfg->DSDSetting.DSD_MANAGER_IP);
20      strcpy(DMS->SNMP_DET.SNMP_MAN_IP,cfg->DSDSetting.SNMP_TRAP_IP);
21          DMS->SNMP_DET.SNMP_MAN_PORT = cfg->DSDSetting.SNMP_TRAP_PORT;
22          DMS->SNMP_DET.DSD_MAN_PORT = 162;
23          
24          if ( checkflag != 1)            //EDITED
25          {std::cout<<"\nDSD Manager IP set to    
26  "<<cfg->DSDSetting.DSD_MANAGER_IP<<"\n";
27           std::cout<<"SNMP TRAP IP set to 
28  "<<cfg->DSDSetting.SNMP_TRAP_IP<<"\n";
29 
30   std::cout<<"SNMP TRAP PORT set to "<<cfg->DSDSetting.SNMP_TRAP_PORT<<"\n";
31           checkflag=1;
32          }
33          
34      try
35      {   //std::cout<<"Entered try\n";
36          bool IPLostErrSet(false),IPGainset(false),FIFOreaderr(false);
37          //DSDCo
38          int nStatus, nLatched,inFifoLoad,MaxBuffRead,lostCount(0);
39          dr = theInput[PORT].SetRxControl(DTAPI_RXCTRL_RCV);
40          
41          if ( DTAPI_OK != dr )                           
42          {   //std::cout<<"\nSetRXControl is not OK";
43          //  return NULL;                                EDITED
44          }
45          
46    #ifdef WIN32
47          while(!_kbhit())
48    #else
49          while(1)
50    #endif
51          {   //EDITED
52              //MaxBuffRead=(inFifoLoad/188)*188;
53              //int DmaSize = ( inFifoLoad > c_ReadBufferSize ) ? c_ReadBufferSize : MaxBuffRead;
54              
55              theInput[PORT].GetFlags(nStatus, nLatched);
56              if ( 0 != (DTAPI_RX_FIFO_OVF & nLatched) ) 
57              {
58                  printf("Fifo overflow for input port %d\t\t\t\t\t[Error]\n",PORT+1);
59                  DMS->SendLog(FIFO_OVERFLOW,PORT+1);
60                  theInput[PORT].ClearFifo();
61                  dr = theInput[PORT].SetRxControl(DTAPI_RXCTRL_RCV);
62                  if ( DTAPI_OK != dr )
63                  {
64                      printf("\nError");
65    
66                  }
67                  else
68                      DMS->SendLog(FIFO_OVERFLOW_CLR,PORT+1);
69              }
70              theInput[PORT].GetFifoLoad(inFifoLoad);
71              inFifoLoad = MINBUFFSIZE + 512;
72              if (inFifoLoad < MINBUFFSIZE+512) 
73              {
74                  lostCount++;
75                  if(lostCount>1000&&!IPLostErrSet)                               
76                  {
77                      lostCount=0;
78                      printf("\nInput lost on port %d\t\t\t\t\t\t[ERROR]",PORT+1);
79                      
80                      DMS->SendLog(INPUT_LOST,PORT+1);
81                      int pid;
82                      /*for(pid=21;pid<8191;pid++)
83                      {
84                          if(cfg->MuxCfg.PORT[PORT].PID[pid].Mux)
85                              DMS->SendLog(PID_REMUX_ERR,pid,PORT+1);
86                      }*/
87                      Mux->PSI.PATdata.Table[PORT].Section[0].no_of_programs = 0;
88                      IPGainset = false;
89                      IPLostErrSet = true;
90                  }
91                  
92    #ifdef WIN32
93                  Sleep(1);
94    #else
95                   usleep(1000);
96    #endif
97              continue;
98              }
99              lostCount = 0;
100             //std::cout<<"\nWill check for IPGAINSET now\n";
101             if(!IPGainset)
102             {   //std::cout<<"IPGAINSET IS FALSE\n";
103                 cfg->OutputConf.Status=true;
104                 printf("\nInput signal detected on port %d\t\t\t\t\t[ OK ]",PORT+1);
105                 
106                 DMS->SendLog(INPUT_GAIN,PORT+1);
107                 /*int pid;
108                 for(pid=21;pid<8191;pid++)
109                 {
110                     if(cfg->MuxCfg.PORT[PORT].PID[pid].Mux)
111                     {
112                         //std::cout<<pid;
113                         DMS->SendLog(PID_REMUX,pid,PORT+1);
114                     }
115                 };*/
116                 IPLostErrSet = false;
117                 IPGainset    = true;
118             }
119             //std::cout<<"IPGAINSET is TRUE\n";
120             //printf("\t%d",inFifoLoad);
121         MaxBuffRead=(inFifoLoad/188)*188;
122             int DmaSize = ( inFifoLoad > c_ReadBufferSize ) ? c_ReadBufferSize : MaxBuffRead;
123             
124             //  fifold=(int)DmaSize;
125             // char data[65424*10];
126     
127     
128             std::cout<<"Before Calling\n";
129                 
130             dr = theInput[PORT].Read(Mux->TSPacket[PORT].data,DmaSize);
131              
132             std::cout<<"After Calling\n";
133 
134             if ( DTAPI_OK != dr )
135             {// std::cout<<"Error in executing Read function\n";
136                 if(!FIFOreaderr)
137                     DMS->SendLog(FIFO_READ_ERR,dr,PORT+1);
138                 
139             }
140             else 
141             {
142                 Mux->ParseAndMuxTS(PORT,DmaSize,cfg,fs);
143    
144             }
145         }
146         return NULL;
147    
148     }
149     catch(...)
150     {
151     //  printf("Error in StartGenericReadThread\n");
152         DMS->SendLog(INTERNAL_ERR,0,0,0,"StartGenericReadThread");
153         return NULL;
154     }
155    }
```

Now following is the snippet of the function definition (which is in another file):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include "DTAPI.h"
#include "DtapiUtility.h"
#include "Dta1xxIoCtl.h"
#include "Dta1xxCodes.h"
#include "Dtu2xxIoCtl.h"
#include "Dtu2xxCodes.h"
#include <iostream>


//+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+ TsInpChannel implementation +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=

//.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.- TsInpChannel::Read -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.
//
// Read data bytes from the input channel using DMA transfers.
//

DTAPI_RESULT TsInpChannel::Read(
                            char* pBuffer,      // [in] Pointer to data to be read from Device
                            int NumBytesToRead) // [in] Number of bytes to be read from Device
{   
    std::cout<<"Entered the function\n";

    // Must be attached.
    //if (!m_Attached)                      EDITED
    //  return DTAPI_E_NOT_ATTACHED;        EDITED

    // Validity check on parameters
    if (NumBytesToRead<0 || NumBytesToRead%4!=0)
        return DTAPI_E_INVALID_SIZE;
    if ((atoi)(pBuffer)%4 != 0)
        return DTAPI_E_INVALID_BUF;

    // Avoid strange effects when NumBytesToRead is zero
    if (NumBytesToRead == 0)
        return DTAPI_OK;

    DTAPI_RESULT dr;

    // Processing is dependent on device category
    if (m_HwFuncDesc.m_DvcDesc.m_Category == DTAPI_CAT_PCI) {

        //-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.- Call the appropiate device IoCtl handler -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-

        DTA1XX_IOCTL_DATA  iod;
        memset(&iod, 0, sizeof(DTA1XX_IOCTL_DATA));
        iod.m_nChIdx                                = GetIndexOnDevice();
        iod.m_Data.m_DataTransDesc.m_pBuffer        = pBuffer;
        iod.m_Data.m_DataTransDesc.m_nNumBytesToTr  = NumBytesToRead;

        dr = ioctl(m_fdDevice, DTA1XX_IOCTL_DMA_USERMEM_READ, &iod);
        if ( dr != DTAPI_OK )
            return dr;
    }
    else if (Category() == DTAPI_CAT_USB) {

        // Read using file IO
        int ret = read(m_fdDevice, pBuffer, NumBytesToRead);
        if ( ret < 0 )
            return DTAPI_E_DEV_DRIVER;
    }
    else                //EDITED
        {   std::cout<<"\n Beginning to read file at /home/rtpl/Desktop/ts.mp4";
            char * storedfilepath = "/home/rtpl/Desktop/ts.mp4";
            int *vedant = open(storedfilepath,O_RDONLY);
            int ret = read(vedant, pBuffer, NumBytestoRead);
        if ( ret < 0)
            std::cout<<"\n File contents cannot be read";                               


        //return DTAPI_E_INTERNAL;          // Unknown device category
        }
    return DTAPI_OK;
}

//.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.- TsInpChannel::ReadDirect -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
//
DTAPI_RESULT TsInpChannel::ReadDirect(
    char*  pBuffer,         //  [in] Buffer to store data
    int  NumBytesToRead,    //  [in] Number of bytes to be read
    int&  NumBytesRead)     // [out] Number of bytes read
{
    return DTAPI_E_NOT_SUPPORTED;
}

//-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.- TsInpChannel::ReadUsingDma -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.
//
// Old name of Read. Still here for backward compatibility.
//
DTAPI_RESULT TsInpChannel::ReadUsingDma(
    char*  pBuffer,         // [in] Buffer to store data
    int  NumBytesToRead)        // [in] Number of bytes to be written to PCI card
{
    return Read(pBuffer, NumBytesToRead);
}
```

Comment: What is `theInput`? There is no declaration of it in the code, that you presented. Please provide [mcve] (additional emphasis: **minimal**). Looks like it is way too much code for the core issue of "function not getting called" (I suspect UB somewhere in the code). What did you observe while stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: There may be more than one function called Read. If you are confused, the fastest way to find out which one is called is with a debugger. Stop at the call line and execute the "step into" action.

Comment: Alright, I'm just a brand new intern in the world of coding so thanks for the info

Comment: @vedantgala "_please don't downvote_" That's not how it works. Everyone is equal here, and I downvoted because of the lack of [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the link @AlgirdasPreidžius ; I'll return with the minimal complete and verifiable example

Comment: @vedantgala The thing is.. You should've already did that before asking, since you should've taken the [tour], read through [help], and [ask].

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that; my bad. Beginners usually have that attitude to skip the "manual" for almost everything